# Finding all simple (without internal cycles) paths in a directed graph with total >1.0 weight

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, complexity

Assume directed graph with each edge being weighted by some positive `float`.

> Problem: find all simple paths (in other words, `[0, 1, 2, 0]` is
>   simple while `[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]` is not due to internal `[0, 1, 0]`
>   cycle) with length `<= cutoff` and "push" them using `pusher`
>   callback.

P.S. There exists some realtime engine (abstracted out by `pusher`) that does such traversal frequently and algorithm should be optimized to be as fast as possible.

```python
from collections import deque
def algorithm(G, source_node, target_node, pusher, cutoff=5):
    queue = deque([[source_node]] if source_node in G else deque())
    while len(queue):
        path = queue.popleft()
        if len(path) == cutoff:  # no sense to keep this path, it not gonna fit the limit
            continue
        adjacency_nodes = G[path[-1]]  # all the neighbours from the latest node in this path
        if not len(adjacency_nodes):  # deadend reached: you can't get any further from this node and it doesn't fit the requirement, so just forgetting it
            continue
        for adjacency_node in adjacency_nodes:
            extended_path = path.copy() + [adjacency_node]  # might some smart linked list do any better here?
            if adjacency_node == target_node:
                pusher(extended_path)  # wow! found one! does not make sense to keep it, since any other path from here will introduce an internal cycle, right?
            else:
                queue.append(extended_path)  # stay calm and keep trying
```

Comment: Why did you write this code? What is it being used for? What would you like out of a review?

Comment: @Reinderien, I'd like community to review it in terms of "Python ideomatic code" (which I am not good with) and, more importantly, algorithm preformance. For example, knowledgeble people might suggest a better datasctructure or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty container like a list or deque is False, so it isn't necessary to use `len()` on them.  This is more "pythonic"

```
while queue:
    ...

    if not adjacency_nodes:
        ...
```

It seems wasteful to add a path to the queue only to discard it because it is too long.  It would be better to check the length before making a copy of the path and adding it to the queue.  Moreover, if `len(path) == is cutoff - 1` the only possible solution is if `target_node` is in `adjacency_nodes`.  So, something like this might be faster:

```
from collections import deque

def algorithm(G, source_node, target_node, pusher, cutoff=5):

    if source_node not in G:
        return

    queue = deque([[source_node]])

    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()

        adjacency_nodes = G[path[-1]]

        if not adjacency_nodes:
            continue

        if len(path) == cutoff - 1:
            if target_node in adjacency_nodes:
                pusher(path[:] + [target_node])

        elif len(path) < cutoff - 1:
            queue.extend(path[:] + [node] for node in adjacency_nodes)
```

If you are trying to optimize for speed, use the profiler in the standard library to see where the algorithm is spending time.

The algorithm is basically a breadth first search of the graph.  Because there is a depth cutoff, a depth first search might be faster because there isn't the overhead of copying the path and keeping the queue of paths to search.  But the only way to know is to implement it and see.

Lastly, the [networkx library](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths) provides `all_simple_paths(G, source, target, cutoff=None)` which is a generator of all simple paths from `source` to `target` with a maximum length `cuttoff`. FYI, networkx uses a DFS search ([source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/simple_paths.html#all_simple_paths)).